# Memory error in classification using GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript

I'm trying to do LULC from 1983 to 2010 using Landsat 5 image but I'm facing memory error in final classified image. I don't know maybe it is because of my samples. My code is

```js
    Map.centerObject (area, 7);  
var image = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_TOA")
.filterBounds(area)    
.filterDate('1983-01-01', '2010-12-31')    
.median()
Map.addLayer(image.clip(area), imageVisParam, 'Landsat Image 2000');

var points = cropland.merge(water).merge(barren).merge(Urban).merge(baresoil).merge(tree)
var predictionBands = image.bandNames();
var samples = image.select(predictionBands).sampleRegions({
  collection: points,
  properties: ['landcover'],
  scale: 30
}).randomColumn();

var trainingSamples = samples.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random', 0.7));
var validationSamples = samples.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random', 0.7));

var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(2000).setOutputMode('classification').train(trainingSamples, 'landcover', predictionBands);
var classified = image.classify(classifier);

var palette =["f9ffa4","98ff00","1c0dff", "a5a5a5","008b2a","d63000","7c0493" ];
Map.addLayer(classified.clip(area), {min: 0,   max: 6,    palette: palette},'Classification ');

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: classified,
  region: area,
  description: 'Composite_Image',
  scale: 30,
});
```

The script is : https://code.earthengine.google.com/fc734ded361a39382faf1ff3a802ec8c

Answer (score 0):

You have a very long date range. When I reduce it to a single year, your classification seems to run. Your area of interest isn't shared, so I cannot test your exact setup. If you need that long date range, you probably need to export your composite as an asset before classifying it.

Comment: But when I try with single year, it gives same memory error. I have also attached link for script too